# How can I fix MOC? JACK finds no valid sound driver

Tags: macos

I am trying to use [MOC](http://moc.daper.net/) on Mac OS X (10.6.6). I have installed it via MacPorts and it gives me the following error (with the `-D` option)

```
Running the server...
Trying JACK...

FATAL_ERROR: No valid sound driver


FATAL_ERROR: Server exited
```

(I didn't post all the stuff that worked. I will if it is needed, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing MOC with vorbis solved the problem. To install it with vorbis via MacPorts, do the following command:

```
sudo port install moc +vorbis
```